# OR shorthand in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I need to check around 20 different columns for a 0 value.

Rather than doing:

WHERE
  BOOK <> 0
  OR ALLO <> 0
  OR ...

Is there a quicker way of doing it?
Something like:
WHERE
  (BOOK,ALLO,...) <> 0

Comment: I think SQL Server allows you to do `0 <> ANY (SELECT BOOK UNION SELECT ALLO SELECT ...)`. The power comes not so much from `UNION`ing all the stuff you want together, but using a subquery to find it. Oracle probably has an equivalent.

Comment: When you say quicker, you just mean you don't want to type all of those columns out? That's ... pretty weird, you only have to type them once and it works forever.

Comment: Are negative values possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it doesn't run anywhere else (MySQL, SQL-Server, Postgres) and it's probably not SQL-standard, it works in Oracle:

```
WHERE 0 <> ANY (BOOK, ALLO, ...)
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d42e3/1)**

---

There is also another way that is standard and works in MySQL and Postgres, but not in Oracle:

```
WHERE (0, 0, ...) <> (BOOK, ALLO, ...)
```

And another standard way (using a Table Values Constructor) that works in Postgres and SQL-Server 2012:

```
WHERE 0 <> ANY (VALUES (BOOK), (ALLO), ...)
```

Comment: This is great, didn't know such a function existed. Thankyou.

Comment: `ANY` is an operator, like `IN`. It's not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
WHERE (book + allo + ...) > 0
```

Comment: Yep, negatives are possible!

Answer (score 1):

If negative values are not possible, you can do this:

```
WHERE BOOK + ALLO + ... > 0
```

If negative values are possible, this is the most concise way I can think of to express it:

```
WHERE ABS(BOOK) + ABS(ALLO) + ... > 0
```

Also, this is database agnostic.

These solutions will only work if null values are not possible, If they are, it would get quite messy.

Comment: You could then use `abs(nvl(book,0)) + ...` for oracle and `isnull(..)` for sql server...